# Portfolio optimisation approach used in the industry

Tags: portfolio-optimization

I was wondering what portfolio optimisation is used by professionals. I know about these 3:

- Mean-variance
- Black-Litterman
- Kelly Criterion

Which one is preferred? Is there some other more robust method?

Comment: All three are used, though they all suffer from the problem that the inputs (such as expected returns and covariances) are difficult to estimate with any precision in real life. (At least Black Litterman attempts to take this issue (input uncertainty) into account).

Comment: Which one should one choose though? What are the pros and cons?